# How often does a molecular machine run in reverse?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, biophysics, stochastic-processes

I was reading the Wikipedia article on [Stochastic thermodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_thermodynamics), and came across this statement in the overview:

> When a microscopic machine (e.g. a MEM) performs useful work it generates heat and entropy as a byproduct of the process, however it is also predicted that this machine will operate in "reverse" or "backwards" over appreciable short periods. That is, heat energy from the surroundings will be converted into useful work. For larger engines, this would be described as a violation of the second law of thermodynamics, as entropy is consumed rather than generated.

My question is, can we calculate a rough estimate of how often this happens?

Also, the classic picture that is often used when describing entropy of a glass shattering vs. a glass unshattering, can this be said to be the same phenomenon except at a smaller (mesoscopic) scale?

Comment: @JiminyCricket. This question seems pretty focused to me. They want to understand conceptually how this happens and at what rate it happens. This is not just a "Biochemistry, what is it???" question

Comment: Well, if you're happy with it - I've not voted to close. @BioPhysicist